# Use old iMac G5 as external Mavericks-style display

Tags: macos, imac, display

I currently have a Mid-2010 iMac (Intel i3 3.06 GHz) running OS X 10.11 "El Capitan" and a really old 17-inch Mid-2005 iMac G5 (PowerPC G5 2GHz) running OS X 10.4.11 "Tiger".

I would like to know if there is any free (if it is software only; cables and stuff are fine) way to convert the old iMac G5 into an external monitor for the newer Intel iMac with the multiple display support introduced in Mavericks (not just mirroring).

Any advice?

Comment: I'd say use Target Display Mode, which temporarily turns almost any Mac into an external display, but your iMac G5 is too old. Does anyone know of an older alternative?

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of [Screen Recycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html)?

Comment: I have checked out Screen Recycler multiple times before, but while it says it does what I want, it is so old, it is essentially unusable. And I do not believe it does what I want.

Comment: Hmm that's a shame. Worth a try though.